# how to parse the data from the database json Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

I want to display the contents of my json in HTML page
I read the lines of my table in the database I put them in a list then I tried to parse the json format, but the problem hen I try to retrieve some data from json I can not by exmple if i want to display a name or something like that

```
@APP.route('/scan',methods=['GET'])
def scan():
    listscan = []
    con = mdb.connect('localhost','testuser', 'test623', 'bd')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tablesd")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        chaine = "Id:" + str(row[0]) + ',' + "HOST_NAME:" + str(row[1]) + "," + "ADDRESS:" + str(row[2]) + "," + "IP:" + str(row[3]) + "," + "TIME:" + str(row[4]) + "," + "DATE:" + str(row[5]) + "," + "CONN:" + str(row[6]) + "," + "ETAT:" + str(row[7]) + "," + "NEWgh:" + str(row[8])
    listscan.append(chaine)

    print json.dumps(listscan)
    return json.dumps(listscan)
```

```js
function scan (){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/scan',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            alert('ok');
            var lang = '';
            $.each(json, function() {
                lang += this['Id'] + "<br/>";
            });
            $("#donnees").html(lang);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('La requête n\'a pas abouti');
        }
    });    
}
```

the result of print json.dumps(listscan):

> ["Id:1,HOST_NAME:,ADDRESS:x:x:x:x:x:x,IP:172.x.x.x,TIME:17:25,DATE:04/04/15,CONN:0,ETAT:null,NEWgh:1", "Id:2,HOST_NAME:,ADDRESS:Y:Y:Y:Y:Y:Y,IP:192.x.x.x,TIME:17:25,DATE:04/04/15,CONN:0,ETAT:null,NEWgh:1"]

I have like display undefined I have not received id.

Comment: Before I dive into your string "chain" there: What is printed at the print line?

Comment: …and is it possible you confused `list` and `listscan`?

Comment: @Klaus D I did what you said

Comment: use only return don't print the results

Comment: OK but where the pb is not in print I did what you say ,the pb that the result of     $("#donnees>table").html(lang);  is undefined

Answer (score 1):

You should update your response (listscan) like:

```
var json = [
 {'Id':1, HOST_NAME:'', ADDRESS:'x:x:x:x:x:x', IP:'172.x.x.x', TIME:'17:25', DATE:'04/04/15', CONN:0, ETAT:null, NEWgh:1},
 {'Id':1, HOST_NAME:'', ADDRESS:'x:x:x:x:x:x', IP:'172.x.x.x', TIME:'17:25', DATE:'04/04/15', CONN:0, ETAT:null, NEWgh:1},
];

$.each(json, function() {
    $('body').append(this['Id'] + '<br\>');
});
```

Here you can find an example: http://jsfiddle.net/guilhermeaferreira/jm86qr0v/

Comment: thanks Guilherme Ferreira but I don't create my listfor  example Value of Id and  HOST_NAME is variable